# Build signed android APK using command line (no manual intervention)

Tags: android, ant, jarsigner

I have a requirement to build the android signed APK automatically using command line without any manual intervention.  I had a quick walk through on the [page](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html) here but it says we need to use Jarsigner or a similar tool to sign the app automatically.

Consider I created an android project using eclipse and sits in my workspace d:\project\goldproj

Do I need to build the project again using ant? What would be the syntax to do so?

Comment: In the page you reference to is everything explained. And it works fine. What is the issue you have with it?

Comment: No, you don't need to rebuild it again with ant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest was would be to use ant build or gradle buid. Ant is kinda simple.

After project is created you need to enhance it to be built with ant. For that you need to navigate into your project's directory and execute

```
android update project -p .
```

This will create all required build files. Not you can build release version of project

```
ant release
```

If you want Ant to sign your apk, you need add following properties into `local.properties` file in your project

```
key.store=
key.alias=
key.store.password=
key.alias.password=
```

Meaning of the properties you can find in the [same page you referenced to](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html).